# Why does PHP have both "resource" data type and "object" data type?

Tags: php

It seems that PHP have two data types for objects: "resource" and "object".

For example the following object is a "resource":

```
$file = fopen("1.txt", "w");

// will print: "resource"
echo gettype($file);
```

And the following object is an "object":

```
$db = mysqli_connect();

// will print: "object"
echo gettype($db);
```

But why there are two data types for objects and not just one data type?

Comment: Resources are legacy from before PHP was object-oriented.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that resources are legacy, but certainly a lower-level representation, and one more geared towards C-style procedural code, from which PHP borrows much of the language's original style. A PHP resource is generally a handle to an external resource, such as a handle to an open file, a socket, or something happening in an external library/extension code. Objects may _wrap_ resources and provide helpful functionality, but inside that object the resource still exists.

Comment: A simple test to illustrate this would be to try to add the `$db` object to `$_SESSION` or call `serialize()` on it, which will raise an error to the effect of "resources cannot be serialized". Another way to think about it is that a resource is generally a reference to state that exists _outside of PHP_. PHP can interact with it, but it doesn't fundamentally own/contain it. Eg: The Mysql resource/handle represents the client-side end of a connection, but the server side is intrinsically linked and cannot be altered, saved, or restored but for interaction over that connection.

Comment: @Sammitch It's not so much that objects wrap resources, as that both objects and resources can wrap C pointers underneath. A class implemented internally can include any data that can be represented in C; it doesn't need to wrap it in a PHP resource first. (Also, please don't post answers in the comment section.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resources are not objects! They are a distinct data type.

The reasons for this are purely historical. PHP didn't have any object-oriented capabilities at the start. The language wasn't meant to be a new language but rather a templating engine for C API. C doesn't have classes.

PHP needed a way to represent a pointer to internal resources, e.g. opened files, database connections, or image canvas. PHP could just use integers to do this, but it would not be enough. The internal resources had to be refcounted and remembered by PHP. PHP, unlike C, has garbage collection and abstracts memory handling*. You can't do that with just an ID number. PHP had to return a variable that internally would point to a resource. It was decided that the simplest way to achieve this is to have a special `resource` data type. Nowadays, it is done with an object, e.g. `CurlHandle`.

Resources were a terrible idea. They do not play nicely with the rest of the type system. They are an exception that is confusing to many PHP users. Since PHP 7, the goal has been to migrate all resources to opaque objects and remove resource data type. While it's not gone yet, it can be considered a legacy and a piece of PHP history.

For more information about `resource` data type and how it works internally visit [www.phpinternalsbook.com](https://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php7/internal_types/zend_resources.html)

<sup>* While most resources have a dedicated function to free them, this is unnecessary as PHP will close the handle and free up the memory once no more variables are pointing to it. The resource data type tracks where the handle is used and whether it's still needed.</sup>